# Custom anchored VWAP

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I've been anchoring a VWAP in TradingView by entering date and time manually as an input, but seeing the recently released "VWAP AA" built-in indicator makes me think that there could be a way to automate what I'm doing.  I would love to be able to automatically anchor two VWAPS from the low and high of the previous day using intraday timeframes, but I'm not able to find a function like "ta.valuewhen" which does a similar thing but capturing the time when a specific event occurs.  I think "VWAP AA" is just using price based calculations and some of the existing time related functions but, since the code is not open, I was wondering if someone in here have been able to find a function or a workaround which addresses my issue.

Thanks greatly.

Comment: The built-in AA VWAP uses some internal feature that is not available in Pine.